# How to type something else rather than what is typed in EditText in Android

Tags: android-edittext

I want to make one application in android where the user is typing in EditText.
But the user does not see what is actualy getting typed, rather it sees a different text in that EditText.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could elaborate on the realtime usage.
However if you want to mask the input, you can use `android:inputType="textPassword"` in the EditText.

Alternately, you can capture the input using `setOnKeyListener` and set the value accordingly.